# How do I add a single row to a list using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

So I have a table of office locations and each column contains the relevant information (i.e. Office Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Country).

I have it set up in the interface for users to select their office, the rest is filled in for them.

I know how to use a generic list and populate it with one column with multiple rows, as I did this with the drop down menu that lists office locations from the same table.

What I don't know is how to populate a generic list with multiple columns from a single row.

For example, here is the code I have for the former which works fine:

```
    private List<string> selectLocs()
    {
        Locs offLoc = new Locs();

        List<string> objList = new List<string>();

        var select = from l in offLoc.Locations
                     orderby l.OFFICE
                     select l;

        foreach (Location loc in select)
        {
            objList.Add(loc.OFFICE);
        }

        return objList;
    }
```

Here is the code for the latter situation, incomplete, since I have no idea how to do the same thing:

```
    private List<string> selectAddr(string strLoc)
    {
        List<string> objList = new List<string>();

        Locs offLocs = new Locs();

        var select = from l in offLocs.Locations
                     where l.OFFICE == strLoc
                     select l;

        //foreach what? in select? Do I even use a foreach loop?


        return objList;
    }
```

Not sure why nobody's asked this before.

Comment: If it seems like nobody's asked it before, but the objective feels common, then you might reconsider if the question you're asking is the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first method could be simplified:

```
private List<string> SelectLocations()
{
    Locs offLoc = new Locs();
    return (from l in offLoc.Locations
            orderby l.OFFICE
            select l.OFFICE).ToList();
}
```

Your second method:

```
private List<string> SelectAddresses(string strLoc)
{
    Locs offLocs = new Locs();
    return (from l in offLocs.Locations
            where l.OFFICE == strLoc
            select l.ADDRESS).ToList();
}
```

UPDATE: If you need several attributes, then return full location object:

```
private List<Location> SelectLocations(string strLoc)
{
    Locs offLocs = new Locs();
    return (from l in offLocs.Locations
            where l.OFFICE == strLoc
            select l).ToList();
}
```

Also try to avoid using Hungary notation (adding prefixes to variable names, which describe variable types). Instead of `strLoc` you can use `locationName`.

Comment: Wow this is helpful, you are awesome. The second one only selects one column (Address) no? What about the other columns l.CITY, l.STATE, l.ZIP?

Comment: Yes, second one selects only one column. If you need all other columns, use third sample. It returns location objects, which have all columns available.

Comment: On the third example I get "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebDirectory.Location>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: Verify return type of your method. It should be list of location objects

Comment: Ah! Thanks, if I could buy you a beer I would.

Comment: Is there a button for that? :)

Answer (score 3):

your first method could be

`return new Locs().Locations.OrderBy(m => m.Office).Select(l => l.OFFICE).ToList()`

Your second query should maybe not return a List, but a location

```
private Location selectAddr(string strLoc)
{
    return new Locs().Locations.FirstOrDefault(m => m.OFFICE == strlLoc);
}
```

or if you want a list of ADDRESS(this is not really clear)

```
private IList<string> selectAddr(string strLoc)
{
    return new Locs().Locations.Where(m => m.OFFICE == strlLoc)
    .Select(l => l.ADDRESS).ToList();
}
```

or a list of Locations

```
private IList<Location> selectAddr(string strLoc)
{
    return new Locs().Locations.Where(m => m.OFFICE == strlLoc)
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Awesome stuff, if I could buy the three of you guys a beer I would.

Answer (score 2):

Sephethus. All of the answers above are valid, but I am not sure they are answering your question. You were asking how to return mutiple columns from a row right?

You can make use of anonymous types to help here, e.g.

```
private IList<string> selectAddr(string strLoc)
{
    Locs offLocs = new Locs();
    var xx = (from l in offLocs.Locations
            where l.OFFICE == strLoc
            select new { l.Address1, l.Address2, l.County });

return xx.Select(a=>String.Concat(x.Address1, x.Address2, x.County).ToList();

}
```

However, you can simplify this even further,

```
private IList<string> selectAddr(string strLoc)
    {
        Locs offLocs = new Locs();
        return (from l in offLocs.Locations
                where l.OFFICE == strLoc
                select String.Concat(l.Address1, l.Address2, l.County)).ToList();

    }
```

Or better still

```
var offLocs = new Locs();
return offLocs.Where(o=>o.Office = strLoc).Select(l=>String.Concat(l.Address1, l.Address2, l.County)).ToList();
```

But that's just a matter of taste!

Comment: I think that second suggestion under "simplify this even further" is going to work perfectly, testing it now. Thanks!